# C++ map insertion using []

Tags: c++, stdmap

I see that the code in subscript operator is like this for a `std::map` when the key is not found. But here they add a default value.

```
__i = insert(__i, value_type(__k, mapped_type()));
```

Now if I do

```
std::map<std::string,int> mapped;
mapped["current"] = 5;
```

I wanted to know how is this pair added to the map using the above statement.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: If the key "current" doesn't exist, `mapped["current"]` creates entry with default value and key "current" and returns reference, to which you assign `5`. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: But it should be allocated through allocator as well, isn't it? like alloc.construct(ptr, pairOfKeyValue) like insert might be doing.

Answer (score 0):

`operator[]` inserts the element of the map if it was not found, and then returns it.

Therefore, the parameters key (__i) and value (__k) are added to the map.

This is one STL implementation:

```
_Tp& operator[](const key_type& k) { // k is the parameter you passed

    iterator i = lower_bound(k);

    // if i -> first >= k then insert a place for the new element.
   if (i == end() || key_comp()(k, (*i).first))
       i = insert(i, value_type(k, _Tp()));

    // return a reference to the element mapped to by the key
    return i -> second;
 }
```

Since a reference is returned, this acts the exact same way as accessing an array does:

You can **assign** `ray[5] = 10` and **access** `int i = ray[5]`.